# Why does a checkbox gets updated only after the code is executed in xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a xslm file with a macro assigned to a button and a checkbox. Pushing the button the macro which is a python script runs and inserts the data into a sheet. The problem is that in the macro I disable the checkbox, but it doesn't affect the checkbox not until the macro has finished.

Below it is an example macro:

```
def insert_data():
    wb = Workbook.caller()

    wb.xl_workbook.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Enabled = False

    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    Range("A1").value = data
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: What I am asking is why the checkbox gets disabled after the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Excel "feature" - try this in VBA:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Enabled = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5")) 'Sleep for 5 Seconds 
    Range("A1").Value = "Some data"
End Sub
```

It only updates the Checkbox after the `Wait` process together with the `Range` call.

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this in a Python function.

Comment: You don't: it's actually mimicking your Python code, except that I mocked the read_csv with a sleep function. But when you copy/paste this in the VBA editor, you will see, that the Checkbox only gets updated after the waiting, i.e. at the end of the script. It seems to be VBA's/Excels behavior, not Python's.

Comment: So, there is no way for the checkbox to update normally.